# Kusto - ranking data based on date, customerId

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am very new to Kusto, used it a few times but need some with the following data example

| Order date | Customer Id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-22 | CD-2123 |
| 2022-08-20 | CD-2123 |
| 2021-09-21 | CD-2123 |
| 2022-10-14 | ZE-8494 |
| 2022-09-23 | ZE-8494 |
| 2022-08-22 | ZE-8494 |
| 2022-10-13 | ME-8494 |
| 2022-05-23 | ME-8494 |

Could someone share a Kusto query that works with the above data and get a new column that has the latest Customer Order when data is ordered by data and grouped by customer id. The most recent order for customerId would start with zero or one.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Expected Result

| Order date | Customer Id | latestCustOrdId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-22 | CD-2123 | 1 |
| 2022-08-20 | CD-2123 | 2 |
| 2021-09-21 | CD-2123 | 3 |
| 2022-10-14 | ZE-8494 | 1 |
| 2022-09-23 | ZE-8494 | 2 |
| 2022-08-22 | ZE-8494 | 3 |
| 2022-10-13 | ME-8494 | 1 |
| 2022-05-23 | ME-8494 | 2 |

Comment: I think you want either row_rank or row_number window function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowrankfunction

Comment: Avoid as possible object names with spaces and/or special characters.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, thank you, I have fixed the data, and there will be no duplicate data for the same date / customer. date format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, 3rd line is 2021

Comment: @jvans, row_rank only works on single columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [partition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator)
- [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rownumberfunction)

```
datatable(["Order date"]:datetime, ["Customer Id"]:string)
[
    datetime(2022-09-22) ,"CD-2123"
   ,datetime(2022-08-20) ,"CD-2123"
   ,datetime(2021-09-21) ,"CD-2123"
   ,datetime(2022-10-14) ,"ZE-8494"
   ,datetime(2022-09-23) ,"ZE-8494"
   ,datetime(2022-08-22) ,"ZE-8494"
   ,datetime(2022-10-13) ,"ME-8494"
   ,datetime(2022-05-23) ,"ME-8494"
]
| partition hint.strategy=native by ['Customer Id'] 
  (
    order by ['Order date'] 
    | extend latestCustOrdId = row_number()
  )
```

| Order date | Customer Id | latestCustOrdId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-22T00:00:00Z | CD-2123 | 1 |
| 2022-08-20T00:00:00Z | CD-2123 | 2 |
| 2021-09-21T00:00:00Z | CD-2123 | 3 |
| 2022-10-14T00:00:00Z | ZE-8494 | 1 |
| 2022-09-23T00:00:00Z | ZE-8494 | 2 |
| 2022-08-22T00:00:00Z | ZE-8494 | 3 |
| 2022-10-13T00:00:00Z | ME-8494 | 1 |
| 2022-05-23T00:00:00Z | ME-8494 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WRQWvCMBTH74V%20h0cuttCMJnZQBU9uBw/Du6WMlgQXsKmkz6ngh99L1uEYoyaHQN4vv394TzVIuz3opGJbp7QD1aBm9dIfaDqdQcXWpwH7jmobRZUBnbH7NI6qOAJaP2Qicyl5vuBSppCx9QuXQs5ZgLI/UMllPg2JYBKPTCLnovDQ7pWXxaL4P45M84dQOX58CvJxwfQ2ZXoe4%205QHUc3ODYODZrewoex%20ER9pGf768o2aD41tFeoZr9aPavB25PvLvdhOIG5z2lEAG6gL6itggPdDugtRG0UrMD153d76lrtktTD6Rf1PJ2k8wEAAA==)